# Algebra Help on Inductive Proof?

Tags: proof, induction

I am trying to learn inductive proofs for a test tomorrow.  I am trying to understand a solution for a problem in a book, but my math is a bit rusty.  Can somebody explain how these are all equal?  I don't understand how the last equation was found from the first equation.

n(n+1)/2 + (n+1) = n(n+1) + 2(n+1)/2 = (n+1)(n+2)/2

Comment: it means that each expression is equal.  they are showing you how they came up with the final expression.  try it yourself with paper and pencil, take the left-most expression and find the sum.

Comment: When I do the first sum, I get (n^2 + n + 2n + 2)/2

Comment: @dan no need to multiply all. it's waste of time. make sence like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19532588/algebra-help-on-inductive-proof/19532804#19532804

Answer (score 0, accepted):

factor the numerator.

```
  (n^2 + n + 2n + 2)/2
= (n^2 + 3n + 2)/2
= ((n+1)(n+2))/2
```

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense.  The order they were doing it in must have been throwing me off

Comment: Yes, sorry I didn't know how, this is my first post

Answer (score 0):

First One is,

```
n(n+1)/2 + (n+1)
( n(n+1)+2(n+1) )/2
( (n+1)(n+2) ) /2
```

Got it?

that final **/2** is common for both.